# Construction of $n$ makes $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

$s_2(n)$ denotes the sum of the standard base-2 digits of $n$.

For a fixed odd number $k>1$, can we construct $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, to make $s_2(nk)<s_2(n)$?

To clarify, that's not $s_2(nk) \lt s_2(k)$. For example, if $k=7$, we can take $n=23=10111_2$ and $nk=161=10100001_2$.

Comment: If $k=2^m+1$ then we would have to have $nk=2^r$, which is impossible.

Comment: For example, if $k=3$, then $s_2(33) = 2 \lt s_2(11)=3$.

Comment: Indeed, taking inspiration from both Douglas and Richard: Find r so that k divides 2^r + 1.  Gerhard "How Can It Go Wrong?" Paseman, 2015.11.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically because $1/k$ has infinitely many $1$s in its binary expansion.

Let $n=\lceil 2^t/k \rceil$ for $t$ large enough, larger than the length of the period of $1/k$ times (the number of digits of $k$ plus $2$). Then $nk$ is just over $2^t$, $nk \lt 2^t+k$, so $s_2(nk)$ is at most $1$ more than the number of digits of $k$, but $s_2(n)$ is greater than the number of digits plus $2$.

Comment: I have a more straightforward solution: Let $m=\lfloor \log_2 k \rfloor +1$, and $n=2^{2m}-2^m-1$.